# Mapping instance to object in Ninject bindings

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, ioc-container

I think this is a relatively straightforward scenario in Ninject but I've been having difficulty finding the right terminology to search for it.

I want to do something like:

```
public interface IClass
{
    IInner Inner { get; }
}

public class ConcreteClass : IClass
{
    public ConcreteClass(IInner inner)
    {
        Inner = inner;
    }

    public IInner Inner {get; private set;}
}

public class Test
{
    private BindingObject _binding {get; set;}

    private override BindingTest()
    {
        //These two lines need some extra configuration
        Kernel.Bind<IClass>().To<ConcreteClass>();
        Kernel.Bind<IInner>().To<ConcreteInner>();

        _binding = new BindingObject(1);
        IClass class1 = Kernel.Get<IClass>();

        _binding = new BindingObject(2);
        IClass class2 = Kernel.Get<IClass>();

        _binding = new BindingObject(1);
        IClass class3 = Kernel.Get<IClass>();

       //The bindings should be set up such that these asserts both pass
       Assert.AreSame(class1.Inner, class3.Inner);
       Assert.AreNotSame(class1.Inner, class2.Inner);
    }
}
```

The implementation of `BindingObject` doesn't matter as this is just a toy example, the idea is just that two `BindingObjects` will compare equal if and only if the `int` passed to their constructor is the same. Likewise, the implementations of `IInner` and `ConcreteInner` don't matter.

So essentially the idea is to set up the binding such that `_binding` is used as a key, and every time `Ninject` needs to inject a new `IInner`, it will just return the existing instance if it has one bound to that particular `_binding`, and create a new one if not. Is there some straightforward in-built way to do this? If not, could I get some guidance (not necessarily a full implementation) about an approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Custom Scope `.InScope()`. That is exactly what you are looking for.

You provide an instance of an object (your `BindingObject`) to the scope func<>. This object is used as an reference when creating/retrieving instances in the kernel.

The Kernel will check if an instance of `IInner` exists with an reference to that object; If so return instance, otherwise create new.

Example:

```
Kernel.Bind<IClass>().To<ConcreteClass>();
Kernel.Bind<IInner>().To<ConcreteInner>().InScope(o => { return _binding ; });

var reference1 = new object();
var reference2 = new object();

_binding = reference1;
var class1 = kernel.Get<IClass>();

_binding = reference2;
var class2 = kernel.Get<IClass>();

_binding = reference1;
var class3 = kernel.Get<IClass>();
```

Here `class1` and `class3` will have the same reference of `IInner`, whereas `class2` will have another reference.

More info at:
http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html under Ninject -> Using Ninject -> Object Scopes. Look near the bottom.
and an little article about scopes: http://bobcravens.com/2010/03/ninject-life-cycle-management-or-scoping/

//Cheers

Comment: Thanks. This requires reference equality between the scope objects to get the same `IInner` instance rather than just equality, but that's good enough. I'm a little confused because most of the documentation I've seen for `InScope` (including the article you linked) talks about the binding being based on the lifecycle of the scope object- i.e. whether it's been garbage collected, which is different to the above examples

Comment: In that case, I would probaly make a Dictionary<int,object> to return the scope objects. But you have to keep the objects alive to ensure the right instance of `IInner` is returned.

Comment: Yeah I agree, a Dictionary is the way to do it